# synchronized method while using wait()

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized

I ran the following code:

```
class Counter extends Thread {

 static int i=0;
//method where the thread execution will start
public void run(){
    //logic to execute in a thread

    while (true) {
        increment();
    }
}

public synchronized void increment()  {
    try {
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " " +  i++);
        wait(1000);
        notify();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
//let’s see how to start the threads
public static void main(String[] args){
    Counter c1 = new Counter();
    Counter c2 = new Counter();
    c1.setName("Thread1");
    c2.setName("Thread2");
    c1.start();
    c2.start();
}
}
```

The result of this code was (added line numbers):

```
1: Thread1 0
2: Thread2 1
3: Thread2 2
4: Thread1 3
5: Thread2 4
6: Thread1 4
7: Thread1 5
8: Thread2 6
stopping...
```

Since increment method is synchronized and since it contains wait(1000) I didnt expect:
1. Thread2 to print 2 consecutive prints: lines 2,3
I expected the threads to interleave their prints
2. on lines 5,6 the i remains 4.

could anyone give me an explanation for this?

Answer (score 9):

Synchronized instance methods like this:

```
public synchronized void foo() { 
    ... 
}
```

are roughly equivalent to:

```
public void foo() {
   synchronized(this) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Do you see the problem here? The synchronization is done on the current instance.

Since you are creating two separate `Thread` objects each `increment` method will synchronize on a different object, thus rendering the lock useless.

You should either make your increment method static (thus the locking is done on the class itself) or use a static lock object:

```
private static final Object locker = new Object();

public void foo() {
   synchronized(locker) {
       ...
   }
}
```

And one final advice: the preferred way to create a thread in java is by implementing `Runnable`, not extending `Thread`.

Comment: And better use the `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` API, and you might want to look into using conditions (`lock.newCondition()`) to communicate between threads.

Comment: If I rewrite this by implementing Runnable, how could I access the thread's name while printing it?

Comment: @Elad: The same as before. Only the line `Counter c1 = new Counter();` changes to `Thread t1 = new Thread(new Counter());` where `Counter` is now just implementing `Runnable`. Then you can do `t1.setName("Thread1");` like before.

Comment: Thanks but i meant what would you write on following line to fetch the threads name:
System.out.println(this.getName() + " " +  i++);
this.getName() can not be used as it is not a method declared on the Runnable interface

Comment: @Elad: In that case you could put another `String` member in the `Counter` class and pass "Thread1" when you create it. Like: `Thread t1 = new Thread(new Counter("Thread1"));`

Answer (score 1):

You are only synchronizing at the instance level.  To synchronize across all `Counter` instances you need the `increment` method to be `static` as well as `synchronized`.

As it stands all your threads run freely, concurrent with each other, because they share no synchronization mechanism.

Comment: Or you need to synchronize on the same object that is common to both `Thread` instances.  Making the method static for this seems like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the code you are looking for

```
class Counter implements Runnable {

    static int i = 0;
    private Lock lock;
    private Condition condition;

    public Counter(Lock lock, Condition condition) {

        this.lock = lock;
        this.condition = condition;
    }


    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                condition.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                System.out.append(Thread.currentThread().getName()).append(" ").println(i++);
                condition.signalAll();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
        Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
        Executor e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        e.execute(new Counter(lock, condition));
        e.execute(new Counter(lock, condition));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! solved the problem of calling to wait() while in a static method!